# How to setup completely wireless network to retrieve data

Tags: networking, router, wifi

I have a situation and I'm not sure the best way (or at least the terminology) to find a solution. There are four rooms that CANNOT have any cabling run into them from the outside. There are 4 machines in each room that take data and are connected via ethernet to a router/switch/etc... within that room as to share its data it collects.

I am wondering if I need to have routers, AP's, or bridges to connect all these devices onto the same network, and then be able for someone to access this hooked up network and be able to get the information from these rooms (again, wirelessly).

I am having trouble how to make sure all these devices are going to be on the same wireless network. I don't want to have to login to each rooms wireless network to pull the data, which is why I think having individual routers in each is not the way to go.

Any networking gurus can shed some light and offer some advice on this completely wireless setup?

Also, I have a good diagram that can help much better than trying to word it all out, but I need 10 reps, is there a way to wave this at all so I can post it for you guys?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if my understanding is correct: You have four rooms (I'm picturing something like trailers at a job site), each with their own standalone networks, you want to connect each standalone network together and you cannot pull cable to any of these locations.

As a networking professional, I always advocate professionally installed cable runs as a means of network access before any other. Experience has taught me that this is most reliable, maintainable and testable way to build networks. I would really recommend you push back against the no new cabling requirement and see if you can either run all the drops in each room to a central IDF or MDF or at the very least run a few cables to each room as uplinks.

Before you consider bridging the networks with wireless is there any possibility you can use Ethernet over Powerline? If the buildings all share the same electrical infrastructure you can bridge the networks this way.

If you must bridge each room's network using wireless what you want is multipoint bridge if you can cover all the rooms with a single bridge (distance and line of sight will determine this) or separate point-to-point bridges for each room.